# How to specify the index with geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a collection with two 2d indexes and I want to use geoNear with one of the indexes, but I don't know how to specify it.

So far geoNear is telling me this: more than one 2d index, not sure which to run geoNear on.

Any solution?

Comment: You might get an answer to this question if you post some of the code that's giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The geoNear command requires that a collection [have at most only one 2d index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2d/#considerations).

You could try using [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/), but it may not allow you to bypass that geoNear index restriction.